# Twitter Bootstrap stencil for the Evolus Pencil Project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prototyping, mockups, mockup-tool

I love [Protoshare's Twitter Bootstrap stencils](http://stencils.protoshare.com/welcome/bootstrap/bootstrap-a/) but unfortunatly I can't afford to use Protoshare.

I'm using Evolus Pencil instead but not really happy with the [stencils provided](https://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/downloads/list?q=label%3aStencil).

Does anyone know of any Twitter Bootstrap stencil(s) for the Evolus Pencil Project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it's not only you who need it. There is [a request on project tracker](http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/issues/detail?id=490) for that. I hope someone will take it into account.

Comment: OK, Thanks!  I'll keep an eye out for it.

Answer (score 12):

This is a late answer, but hope someone can find it useful.

There are two resources for Bootstrap Pencil stencil, thanks for those  who spent their time creating them:

1. https://github.com/ryuslash/BootstrapStencils by Tom Willemse
2. https://github.com/nathanielw/Bootstrap-Pencil-Stencils by Nathaniel Watson

Answer (score 2):

Please, visit [a request on project tracker](https://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/issues/detail?id=490) again.

I created a "Stuff" design similar to the bootstrap. Not a stencil but it meets my needs and is easily configurable and easy to style.

Comment: How to install that to Pencil?

Comment: Click on the tab "My Stuff" and then click the right button and go to the "Import new private collection" option.